# Warming up Azure Web App after deploy (without using deployment slots)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, azure-deployment

We have a number of Azure Web Apps which we deploy to regularly (several times a week). The deploys are performed using the Zip Push Deploy method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push), and this works very well.

Our issue is that the different web apps are not properly started until the first requests are issued against the server, which means that the first user gets a large performance penalty. We tried to resolve this by making a request right after the deploy is done, but it seems that we too often hit the old version of the web app instead of warming up the new one.

I know that we could use deployment slots and their warmup-functionality, but for many reasons, deployment slots are not an option for us right now.

Is there any way we can know when a deployment is finished so that we don't trigger a warmup call before the new code is up and running (e.g. user a Powershell script)?

Currently we use a Powershell query similar to the one below to hit the app services, but often they return very quickly due to the fact that the deployment has not yet completed:

```
# Warmup Azure service
$warmupUrl = "https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/"
Write-Output "Making request to $warmupUrl"
$stopwatch = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

Try {
  # Allow redirections on the warm up
  $response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $warmupUrl - 
MaximumRedirection 10 -TimeoutSec 240
   $stopwatch.Stop()
   $statusCode = [int]$response.StatusCode
  Write-Output "$statusCode Warmed Up Site $TestUrl in 
$($stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)s ms"
} catch {
    #$_.Exception|format-list -force
} Finally
{
     $stopwatch.Stop()
     Write-Output "Warmed Up Site $warmupUrl in 
 $($stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)s ms"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance that you are using async zipdeploy and not waiting for it? If you wait for it, the new bits should be effective pretty quickly. To be safe, wait 10 seconds after the deployment (to allow file change notifications to propagate) and I would not expect that you'll ever hit the old version.

Comment: Hi @david-ebbo. Thank you for the reply. We are currently not using the async option and our "hack" is the one you suggested, namely to wait a number of seconds. I just hoped that I could use a method that did not rely on a fixed waiting period. It would be nice if Azure web app supported some kind of notification when the deployment is complete, or that an Azure web app could execute a script when the deploy is completed.

Comment: The **deployment** really is complete when zip deploy is done, in the sense that all files have been copied where they belong. What's missing is that the **runtime** needs time to react to it, and that's less predictable, especially if you have multiple instances.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to know when the runtime is done reacting to the change, but until that is possible (if it ever is), we will use a timeout of around 10 seconds.